# Retrofit: skip records with unwanted data

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit to call an API which returns a list of objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "NAME": "text",
        "VALUE": 10
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "NAME": "text",
        "VALUE": 20
    },
    ...
]
```

My Retrofit API is:

```
@Headers("content-type: application/json")
@GET("FAMILY_VALUES")
suspend fun getFamilyValues(): List<Family>
```

Everything is ok so far. Unfortunately sometimes the server sends data with null values:

```
[
    ...
    {
        "ID": 5,
        "NAME": "text",
        "VALUE": null
    },
    ...
]
```

I don't know why it happens. The server is out of my control and I cannot change the received data. However this records are useless to my logics and I would like to exclude them from my output List, so that the final list doesn't contain an item with ID=5 at all.

How can I achieve this with Retrofit and GSON? My ugly workaround is to loop the list later and discard the items, I'm looking for a more performing solution that doesn't add the useless items at all.

UPDATE: another solution I've tried was to add a JsonDeserializer that skips the wrong records but it didn't work. My hope was that GSON skipped the null returned items but instead it added null values.

```
class FamilyDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Family> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): Family? {
        json as JsonObject
        return if ((json.get("VALUE") !is JsonNull)) {
            Family(
                json.get("ID").asInt,
                json.get("NAME").asString,
                json.get("VALUE").asInt
            )
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `custom JSON deserializer`  with `Gson`

Comment: I have tried it but if I set the return value to null, Gson doesn't skip it but adds null values

Comment: Can you add your custom JSON deserializer code?

Comment: Done. Maybe there's something wrong in it?

Comment: No, your code looks fine. Gson does (to my knowledge) not support that `JsonDeserializer` (or `TypeAdapter`) return _no value_. As (hacky) workaround you could in addition to your JsonDeserializer possibly register a custom [`InstanceCreator`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html) which creates a List whose `add` method ignores `null` values. Maybe other JSON libraries have better support for this use case.